# how to use CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent properly with ARC enabled?

Tags: objective-c, ios, url, ftp, automatic-ref-counting

I am building an app with an FTP connection, and I am trying to use the [SimpleFTPSample](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleFTPSample/Introduction/Intro.html) app as an example. I have ARC enabled in my app, while it is not disabled in the sample tutorial.

Because of using ARC, I ran into an issue with the follwing code:

```
url = [NSMakeCollectable (CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent
(NULL, (CFURLRef) url, (CFStringRef) self.dirNameText.text, true)
) autorelease];
```

1) after removing NSMakeCollectable and autorelease:

```
url = (CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent
(NULL, (CFURLRef) url, (CFStringRef) self.dirNameText.text, true));
```

Now I have three ARC **casting errors**:
"Case of Objective-C pointer type NSURL to C pointer type 'CFURLRef (...) requires a bridged case" and one semantic issue: "Incompatible pointer types assigning to 'NSURL *__strong' from 'CFURLRef'".

As Xcode suggests, I use __bridge for the conversions, but I still have one of the casting error and the semantic error with the code below:

```
url = (CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent
(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, 
(__bridge CFStringRef) self.dirNameText.text, true));
```

I have been searching for a solution, but could not find an exact fit. I modified my code  using CFBridgingRelease as seen in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/5773/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2):

```
url = CFBridgingRelease(CFURLCreateCopyAppendingPathComponent
(NULL, (__bridge CFURLRef) url, 
(__bridge CFStringRef) self.dirNameText.text, true));
```

...but the app was still breaking with an EXC_BAD_ACCESS thread.

If you know what I am missing, please let me know!
Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't seem like you need to use Core Foundation at all.  Try this:

```
url = [url URLByAppendingPathComponent:self.dirNameText.text isDirectory:YES];
```

Comment: Rob, thanks for your response! In fact, both codes work perfectly. I had a delegate issue in my code and the self.dirName.text was nil, so that is why it broke.